# why does the input type=reset is not working?

Tags: html, forms, reset

Here is the code. When I try to use input type reset, it is not working. I tried to remove it outside the div, still it's not working.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s4"></div>
        <div class="col s4">
            <form class="form"  action="<?=base_url()?>item/updatedata/<?=$this->uri->segment(3)?>" method="POST">
                <div class="row">
                    <label>ITEM ID</label>
                    <input type="text" readonly="" value="<?=$items->item_id?>" class="validate">
                    <label>ITEM NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" value="<?=$items->item_name?>" name="item_name" class="validate">
                    <label>ITEM DESCRIPTION</label>
                    <input type="text" value="<?=$items->item_desc?>" name="item_desc" class="validate">
                    <label>ITEM PRICE</label>
                    <input type="text" value="<?=$items->item_price?>" name="item_price" class="validate">
                    <div class="col s6">
                        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light " type="submit" value="SUBMIT">Submit
                            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s6">
                        <input  class="btn waves-effect waves-light red" type="reset" value="Reset">
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col s4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `input` type `reset` resets all `form` values to *default values*.

Since for all `input` elements, you have given a `value`, this acts as the default value for those elements.

When you click `Reset` button, all the values are set to default values that you have given.

If you remove `value` attributes, the reset will set all the values to blank (in case of text), and it will work as you expected.

Comment: This just isn't working for me. I've read multiple posts that state the same thing, but I can't seem to get my reset buttons to work. It's extremely frustrating.

Comment: Need to take a look at your code to be able to help you out. Have you posted a question with more details? Or you can also point me to your Stackblitz/Jsfiddle etc.

Answer (score -1):

As long as your `<input type ="reset">` tag is inside the form there shouldn't be any problem. I'ts working fine in the reproduced fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/prashu421/3wa9v7p6/

If that isn't working for you, you can use  as below

```
<button  class="btn waves-effect waves-light red" type="reset" value="Reset" > Reset </button>
```

Comment: The OP states that it doesn't work, and their code shows that it is in a form.

Comment: You've failed to explain why `<button type="reset">` should work when `<input type="reset">` does not. (This is probably because it *won't* work, for the same reason.)

Answer (score -2):

Please use `<input type='reset' value='Reset'/>`  tag with in the `form` tag

Comment: Hello @Bala, Welcome to Stackoverflow, please add some more details to your answer, also the code you provide will return an error, it lacks a single quote in the value attribute.

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuery

```js
    $('input:reset').click(function () {      
        $('input:text').attr('value', '');
    });
```

Comment: You've provided a live demo in your answer, but it throws errors.